# Testing ActiveStorage attachments (FileNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm getting an error testing the ActiveStorage attachment.  The code is something like this:

```rb
class AssemblyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'Updating svg attachment should upload the updated file' do
    @assembly = Assembly.create(name: assemblies(:head_gasket).name,
                                image: 
    fixture_file_upload('files/track-bar.svg', 'image/svg+xml'))
    assert @assembly.image.attached?
    assert_not_empty @assembly.image.download
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following error
`Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError` when @assembly.image.download is called.  The `attached?` assertion is passing, but I can't figure out why the download of the file is failing.  Also, nothing shows up in the `tmp/storage` directory, where the ActiveStorage is configured to store files.

Comment: I don't think you need to test that activestorage works.

Comment: I'm not testing if activestorage works.  I'm testing a method that relies on a file stored in activestorage.  Sorry, I posted a snippet of what is actually happening to make it easier to understand/isolate.  I'm actually testing another method, that relies on a file stored in activestorage.

Answer (score 7):

While digging in the ActiveStorage code [I found this snipped](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/df462d5880a139d591d0800ca49b1608f43dc6fa/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb#L58) which relies on actual database commits to execute the document upload (or save to disc):

```rb
after_commit(on: %i[ create update ]) { attachment_changes.delete(name.to_s).try(:upload) }
```

In case you use **database transactions** in the test environment this will then not store the document.

To solve this you can trigger the commit callback manually:

```rb
run_callbacks(:commit)
```

So in your case this might work:

```rb
class AssemblyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'Updating svg attachment should upload the updated file' do
    @assembly = Assembly.create(name: assemblies(:head_gasket).name,
                                image: 
    fixture_file_upload('files/track-bar.svg', 'image/svg+xml'))
    @assembly.run_callbacks(:commit) # Run commit callback to store on disk
    assert @assembly.image.attached?
    assert_not_empty @assembly.image.download
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@assembly = Assembly.create(name: assemblies(:head_gasket).name)
@assembly.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.name', content_type: 'mime/type')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the blob directly (which is how the direct upload process works) and then attach it so the blob is guaranteed to already be uploaded.

```
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
  io: File.open(Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/test.csv")),
  filename: "test.csv",
  content_type: "text/csv",
  identify: false
)
@model.file.attach(blob)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same on production and in my case it happened because user uploaded broken png file

so I added validation to prevent corrupted files from being uploaded using the demension option, because broken images will never have a dimension value.

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates :image, content_type: %w[image/png image/jpg image/jpeg],
            dimension: { width: { min: 50, max: 5000 },
                         height: { min: 50, max: 5000 }}

end
```

also I used these 3 gems to make everything work properly

#Gemfile

```
gem "active_storage_validations"
gem "ruby-vips"
gem "image_processing"
```